# Vertx to Quarkus-migration

Tags: quarkus, vert.x

I've started porting my Vertx application to Quarkus. The application is based on different verticles, the app starts, is ready and after the first successful HTTP-response, I always get a 404 error. My HTTP-verticle is here:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class HttpVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Inject
    EventBus eb;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HttpVerticle.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void start() {
        this.initHttpServer();
    }

    private void initHttpServer() {
        Router router = Router.router(vertx.getDelegate());

        router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create());
        router.get("/event/:eventID").handler(this::handleTrackingEvent);
        router.get("/cache/fill").handler(this::fillCacheWithData);
        router.get("/cache/purge").handler(this::purgeCache);
        router.get("/health/check").handler(this::checkHealth);

        HttpServerOptions httpServerOptions = new HttpServerOptions();
        httpServerOptions.setCompressionSupported(true);

        HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer(httpServerOptions).getDelegate();
        httpServer.requestHandler(router).listen(8080);
    }

    private void checkHealth(final RoutingContext routingContext) {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.request().response();
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        response.end();
    }

    private void purgeCache(final RoutingContext routingContext) {
        eb.send(Constants.REDIS_PURGE_EVENTBUS_ADDRESS, "");
        eb.send(Constants.CACHE_PURGE_EVENTBUS_ADDRESS, "");

        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.request().response();
        response.setStatusCode(200);
        response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        response.end();
    }

    private void fillCacheWithData(final RoutingContext routingContext) {
        LOGGER.info("Filling caches with data ... ");
        LOGGER.fine("Reading JSON-data");

        FileSystem fs = vertx.fileSystem().getDelegate();
        fs.readFile("META-INF/data.json")
                .onSuccess(buf -> {
                    JsonArray jsonArray = buf.toJsonArray();
                    for (Object aJsonArray : jsonArray) {
                        JsonObject obj = (JsonObject) aJsonArray;
                        LOGGER.fine("Sending message to cache-verticles: " + obj);
                        eb.send(Constants.CACHE_STORE_EVENTBUS_ADDRESS, obj);
                        eb.send(Constants.REDIS_STORE_EVENTBUS_ADDRESS, obj);
                    }
                    routingContext.end();
                })
                .onFailure(err -> {
                    LOGGER.info(err.getMessage());
                    routingContext.fail(err);
                });
    }

    private void handleTrackingEvent(final RoutingContext routingContext) {

        String userAgent = routingContext.request().getHeader("User-Agent");
        String eventID = routingContext.request().getParam("eventID");

        UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
        TrackingMessage trackingMessage = new TrackingMessage();
        trackingMessage.setMessageId(uuid.toString());
        trackingMessage.setProgramId(eventID);

        JsonObject message = JsonObject.mapFrom(trackingMessage);

        if (null == eventID) {
            routingContext.fail(400);
            return;
        }
        eb
                .<JsonObject>request(Constants.CACHE_EVENTBUS_ADDRESS, message)
                .onSuccess(res -> {
                    JsonObject result = res.body();
                    if (result.isEmpty()) {
                        sendResponse(routingContext, 404, Json.encode("ProgramId not found"));
                        return;
                    }

                    TrackingMessage tmpMsg = Json.decodeValue(result.encode(), TrackingMessage.class);
                    tmpMsg.setUserAgent(userAgent);

                    String enrichedData = Json.encode(tmpMsg);

                    eb.send(Constants.KINESIS_EVENTBUS_ADDRESS, enrichedData);
                    sendResponse(routingContext, 200, enrichedData);
                })
                .onFailure(err -> {
                    LOGGER.severe(err.getMessage());
                    routingContext.fail(err);
                });
    }

    private void sendResponse(final RoutingContext routingContext, int statusCode, final String message) {
        HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.request().response();
        response.setStatusCode(statusCode);
        response.putHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        if (message != null)
            response.end(message);
        else
            response.end();
    }
}
```

and I get the following error after the first successful HTTP-request:

```
2024-02-09 14:13:29,716 DEBUG [WebApplicationException] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) Restarting handler chain for exception exception: jakarta.ws.rs.NotFoundException: HTTP 404 Not Found
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RestInitialHandler.handle(RestInitialHandler.java:71)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:121)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:147)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.RestInitialHandler.beginProcessing(RestInitialHandler.java:48)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:23)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.vertx.ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.handle(ResteasyReactiveVertxHandler.java:10)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1286)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:144)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:59)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$1.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:37)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1286)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:144)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder$13.handle(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:339)
        at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.ResteasyReactiveRecorder$13.handle(ResteasyReactiveRecorder.java:332)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouteState.handleContext(RouteState.java:1286)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImplBase.iterateNext(RoutingContextImplBase.java:177)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RoutingContextImpl.next(RoutingContextImpl.java:144)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:68)
        at io.vertx.ext.web.impl.RouterImpl.handle(RouterImpl.java:37)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$2.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:83)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.options.HttpServerCommonHandlers$2.handle(HttpServerCommonHandlers.java:66)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:162)
        at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder$1.handle(VertxHttpRecorder.java:138)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequestHandler.handle(Http1xServerRequestHandler.java:67)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerRequestHandler.handle(Http1xServerRequestHandler.java:30)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.emit(EventLoopContext.java:55)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.DuplicatedContext.emit(DuplicatedContext.java:179)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xServerConnection.handleMessage(Http1xServerConnection.java:174)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.read(ConnectionBase.java:159)
        at io.vertx.core.net.impl.VertxHandler.channelRead(VertxHandler.java:153)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.onHttpRequestChannelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:160)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:83)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xUpgradeToH2CHandler.java:124)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.end(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:61)
        at io.vertx.core.http.impl.Http1xOrH2CHandler.channelRead(Http1xOrH2CHandler.java:38)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: You apparently have RESTEasy Reactive, which likely conflicts with your own router. For migrating a Vert.x application to Quarkus, especially one that is heavy on Vert.x Web usage, I'd recommend reading https://quarkus.io/blog/magic-control/

Comment: why are you injecting the event-bus, if you can get it directly from class's `vertx.eventBus()`?